# Azure: Failed to retrieve user's profile photo and upload to the Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am trying to fetch profile photos of users through Microsoft Graph by running the below query:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/USER_Name/photo`

After retrieving the photos of the required users, I have copied photos on the disk. I want to upload it to Azure blob programmatically

I have created a storage account. I have registered an application in Azure AD for connecting to Microsoft Graph. I have granted the required permissions.

But I am stuck on fetching the profile photo itself.

Could anyone help me on achieving the above scenarios?

Comment: you just queried the metadata, to get the photo itself, add `$value` at the end of your API URI

Comment: @Swastik Rai, when you. say you are stuck, what is the issue. Are you receiving any errors. If you provide details of the issue/errors you encounter, then the community can try and help you. If the details aren't provided then people can make educated guess and help you or ignore this query and help others who have provided enough info in their queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the profile photo of a user via Ms Graph please try the below query:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/UPN/photo/$value`

***I have tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got profile photo successfully like below***:

[image]

**To upload pictures to the Azure blob storage, you can refer the below link for more information in detail:**

[Use Microsoft Graph to Retrieve Users Photos and Store Them as Azure Blobs With C# – Mihai-Albert.com](https://mihai-albert.com/2020/08/12/use-microsoft-graph-to-retrieve-users-photos-and-store-them-as-azure-blobs-with-c/)